# Installing rvm on Debian gives an error: "rvm_warn: command not found"

Tags: ruby, rvm, debian

I am trying to install rvm on my newly installed Debian. But I get this error:

```
bash: line 234: rvm_warn: command not found
```

Looking at the contents of the installer file, it is trying to output this message:

```
Curl returned 141 - it is result of a segfault which means it's Curls fault.
Try again and if it crashes more than a couple of times you either need to
reinstall Curl or consult with your distribution manual and contact support.
```

I tried re-installing curl, but it did not fix the problem.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are two separate errors you need to report the first one to RVM: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

The second one is a problem in your system, you can add `--debug` or `--trace` flags to the installer to see on which urls it fails, then you should be able to reproduce it without RVM - this should be reported back to your distribution as `141` is unexpected `curl` error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I removed the version of `curl` which I had installed from the main Debian repos, and downloaded and installed a newer version of `curl` from it's website. Using this new version I was able to install `rvm`.